# map of graded rings and projective schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $\phi$ a morphism between $S$ and $R$, two graded rings (there is a $d>0$ such that $S_{n}$ maps to $R_{dn}$ for all $n$). How could I show that this induces a morphism of schemes
$$\operatorname{Proj} R - V(\phi(S^+))\to \operatorname{Proj} S,$$
where $S^+$ is the irrelevant ideal?

Comment: This is a standard fact that you should be able to find in any textbook in algebraic geometry.

Comment: could you give me some references, please? Thanks

Comment: What book(s) do you use ?

Comment: now I'm using the geometry of schemes (eisenbud) and ravi vakil

Comment: I am really surprised that you didn't found it in Vakil. Anyway, I just reached the perfect number of answers, so I would like just comment. We have $V(\phi(S^+))=\cap_f V(\phi(f))$, where $f$ ranges the homogeneous elements of $S$. So the LHS is $\cup_f D(\phi(f))$. Now $\phi$ induces a homomorphism of homogeneous localizations $S_{(f)}\to R_{(\phi(f))}$ which defines a morphism of affines open subschemes $D(\phi(f))\to D(f)$. Glueing this morphisms when $f$ varies will give you the morphism you are after. If this answer suits you, I ask you as a favor to copy it into an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

As Cantlog says, this can be found in every introduction to algebraic geometry. For example EGA II, 2.8. Or Görtz-Wedhorn, Remark 13.7.